# mmap performance on iOS with frequent writes

Tags: ios, core-graphics, memory-mapped-files

I am using the `mmap` function on iOS in a drawing app. I have a file that uses `mmap` and then I create a `CGBitmapContext` from that memory. The user may perform many core graphics operations on this `CGBitmapContext` with their finger, which will cause the memory to be updated constantly.

How often will this flush to the flash storage and is this a concern for wearing out the flash storage or for performance? I haven't noticed anything bad in my tests, but I am not familiar enough with `mmap` to know for sure.

Comment: Nothing but crickets here on stackoverflow unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS is pretty smart about how often it flushes to disk. I have noticed that when I background the app, as long as I call `msync`, i.e. `msync(self.memoryMap, self.memoryMapLength, MS_SYNC);` it flushes properly.

While I use the app, even if there is a crash or sudden termination, usually all data is saved. If I kill my app while debugging, sometimes the last few changes are not saved, but usually everything is saved.

So my conclusion is that this is not a concern. iOS is not constantly writing to disk, it is writing to disk at smart intervals.